# How to prevent ProGuard from obfuscating a library imported from a JAR file?

Tags: java, android, proguard

There is a library that I have imported using Android Studio's ***Import from JAR/AAR file*** dialog box. However, ProGuard is obfuscating this library, and hence the methods in those classes are not visible in my other modules.

I tried creating a file with name ***proguard-rules.pro*** beside the ***build.gradle*** file in the generated library directory. However, this file is not picked up by ProGuard, though it is what I expected could happen.

The library JAR that I'm importing has 4 classes in two sub-packages under the package `com.merchant.lib`. These are the ProGuard rues that I have added.

```
-keep class com.merchant.lib.** { *; }
```

The ***build.gradle*** file which is generated by Android Studio is as follows:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file("merchant-lib.jar"))
```

I expect ProGuard to keep the classes in that JAR file intact, without any modifications. However still ProGuard is processing this JAR file, and I cannot access those classes.

How can I prevent ProGuard from obfuscating the library files?

Comment: break the problem into smaller problem, first give qualified sub-package in proguard if it works then add more and then roll up

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @DeepakJoshi No Deepak. I've raised a ticket to DexGuard team and they said that wasn't supported as of then. We ended up buying a licence for the test app module too.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati, Is it possible to access the link to the ticket raised?

Comment: @DeepakJoshi I don't think so. Also, I've since moved to a new company, so don't have access to the link as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find an elegant and simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

get the package name from jar file and use `-dontwarn`

```
-dontwarn  com.sun.mail.**
-dontwarn  javax.mail.**
```

Comment: Don't warn is a different thing I believe. When I tried adding this to the app's build.gradle, Gradle was able to compile fine, but I started seeing errors in runtime.

Comment: add this line into proguard.pro file

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant I did add it to the app's proguard.pro file. It compiled fine but is throwing a noclassdeffoundexception

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to include the jar file as an input instead of as a library in your proguard.pro file:

```
-injars jar-in-question.jar
```

not

```
-libraryjars jar-in-question.jar
```

All this in ADDITION to the -keep statement in your question.

Answer (score 0):

consumerProguardFiles 'lib-proguard-rules.txt' should be set for libraries

> To add the ProGuard rules to your library project, you must specify
> the file's name with consumerProguardFiles property, inside the
> defaultConfig block of your library's build.gradle file. For example,
> the following snippet sets lib-proguard-rules.txt as the library's
> ProGuard configuration file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'lib-proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    ...
}
```

Please, see the [original doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations) for more details